# Cross-reference to equation with cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

How can I get `cleveref` to produce the following:

> Inserting Equation (1) into (2) yields ...

i.e., I don't want the word "Equation" to pop up before (2), which i have when simply using

```
Inserting \Cref{eq:1} into \Cref{eq:2} yields ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\labelcref` for the second cross-reference. Or, assuming the `amsmath` package is loaded as well, just write `\eqref` to generate the second cross-reference.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1} a \end{equation} % generate two dummy equations
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2} b \end{equation}

Inserting \cref{eq:1} into \labelcref{eq:2} yields \dots

Inserting \cref{eq:1} into \eqref{eq:2} yields \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: @YossiGil - Your claim that "output is the same" (for `\cref` and `\Cref`) is not correct -- at least not when it comes to generating cross-references to equations. To keep the output the when changing `\Cref` to `\cref`, you should also change `\usepackage{cleveref}` to `\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}` in order to get "Equation" instead of "eq.".

Comment: In general, they are distinct.  Are you saying they ar distinct in the particular example?

Comment: @YossiGil - When one generates cross-references to equations, the outputs of `\cref` and `\Cref` are *very* distinct: `eq.` vs. `Equation` for the singular case, and `eqs.` vs. `Equations`  for the plural case. I used `\Cref` precisely because the OP seemed to prefer to output `Equation`. If you change my code from `\Cref` to `\cref`, you should also change the way `cleveref` is loaded, so as to get back to `Equation`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change with `\crefname{}{}{}`. Enter the environment in the first bracket, then the singular form, and last the plural form.
`\crefname{equation}{}{}` would remove any form of Eq/Eqs and only print (1), (2).

Comment: AFAICT, the OP wanted to remove the label "Equation" only from the second cross-reference, not from both of them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/230469)

Comment: The word 'Equation' is usually unwanted in any reference thus (#) is sufficient, but can be spelled out where it is needed.